# Ansible not changing into directory to run command(s)

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible `2.8.4-1.el7` in order to automate some tasks. Since I'm starting learning the tool, I'm going through the official documentation most of the times (more specifically, I'm following [these examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#examples)).

I'm just trying to execute a script that manages the Tomcat instance(s):

```
- name: Stop service
  command: "{{ script_manager }} stop"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ path_base }}/bin/"
```

I'm setting those variables beforehand:

```
path_base: /some/path/tomcat9_dev/

script_manager: tomcat9_dev
```

...but I'm still getting this error message:

```sh
TASK [tomcat : Stop service] ***************************************************
fatal: [tld.server.name]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "cmd": "tomcat9_dev stop", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

It looks like it's not changing into that directory first to execute the command. Any clues?

> I know the location exists, I can SSH into the server(s) and `cd` into it.

---

**UPDATE:** If I do `"{{ path_base }}/bin/{{ script_manager }} stop"` it works fine. In any case, what's a better approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current directory is not part of the PATH in *nix OS. Changing dir to the correct location is not enough.

If you really want to call your script like this, you have to add `{{ path_base }}/bin/` to your user's PATH.

Meanwhile, you can take advantage of `chdir` by calling your script relative to the current dir:

```yaml
- name: Stop service
  command: "./{{ script_manager }} stop"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ path_base }}/bin/"
```

Furtermore, you are IMO on the wrong track: tomcat should be a registered service on the machine and you should manipulate it with the relevant modules: either the generic [`service`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html#service-module) or one of the specific [`systemd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/systemd_module.html#systemd-module), [`runit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/runit_module.html#runit-module),[`sysvinit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/sysvinit_module.html#sysvinit-module)...

Example with service:

```yaml
- name: Make sure tomcat_dev is stopped
  service:
    name: tomcat_dev
    state: stopped
```

Comment: The `./` "trick" did it. And regarding the managed service options, I started with that one, but I'm always getting `Could not find the requested service tomcat: host`, plus I see that the admins always use that script to start/stop the servers with tons of parameters, so I went the same route.

Comment: Probably far too late but if may still help: [one out of the plethora of ressources](https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/e6e99dad070a78d5dab24ff3ae032ed1) I found searching for ["tomcat as a systemd service"](https://www.qwant.com/?client=ext-firefox-sb&q=tomcat+as+a+systemd+service&t=web) in my favourite search engine:. If you are not using systemd, just change the search term.